# Is there a difference between Nintendo 64 controllers used on PAL and NTSC systems?

Tags: controllers, region-lock, nintendo-64

Is it possible to use the controllers from an NTSC (Japanese / US) Nintendo 64 system on a PAL (EUR) system? Are they the same item or is there a difference?

Comment: I don't see why they'd be different; just the power supply and display output devices for consoles should differ from region to region.

Comment: @fbueckert - It appears the original NES controllers were region locked: http://retro.mmgn.com/NES/Forums/Nes-Controller-NTSC-to-PAL-Conversion

Comment: Interesting.  I hadn't known that was a thing.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 So, did you try?

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 Which controllers were you trying to connect?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the controllers are identical, I'm fairly sure the controllers themselves are not going to have any region-specific differences.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a difference between the cables of the controllers. Some controllers (I think the controllers from PAL systems) have a ferrite bead at the end of the cable. There are also different types of ferrite beads (I think 2).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question with additional details [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243446/will-an-ntsc-n64-rumble-pak-work-in-a-pal-controler).
Basically @electronbeam is correct the standard controllers for all regions send the exact same signal down the wire.

Comment: I can also confirm that I have now tried many (at least 50) Japanese controllers on PAL consoles and there is no difference. This includes using rumble packs and Pokemon transfer packs from PAL regions inside "Japanese" controllers and they all work the same. This includes controllers that were exclusive releases in Japan.